# Show "Loading/Loader/Progress Bar" after button click in ASP.NET (Web Form)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

In my login page I need a function where user clicks on the "Login" button and a loader appears (GIF or any kind of message) before page fully loads.

I tried many ways to do that but I wasn't successful. The loader only shows up after page is fully loaded.

Is there any function that it can display the loader while page is loading or server is processing?

[image]

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem.

Comment: you're looking for `asp:UpdateProgress`

Comment: Thanks @fubo for your quick response but unfortunately I can't use UpdatePanel on that page since there are some CSS styles where they get disappeared if page doesn't fully PostBack and this also applies to ASP:ScriptManager, as soon as I put ScriptManager in my page the RequiredFieldValidator doesn't validate my fields until it does PostBack.

Comment: Try to perform login using `ajax` as it is async.

Comment: @Akshay Thanks for your response, can you show an example?

Comment: Perform ajax call as  `$.ajax({ url : 'your_url', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', data: 'your_data', dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' success: function() { } });` Before calling ajax you can show the spinner and hide it in success function.

Comment: @Akshay how can I connect the "Login" button to this function?

Comment: You can call this function on Login button click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87004/discussion-between-akshay-and-kevin-maxwell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
$('#btn_id').click(function () {     
    var username = $('#username').val(); 
    var password = $('#password').val(); 

    if (username != "" && password != "") { 
    $('#Loader').modal(); 
    } 
});
```